# Vue - Access Mixin Data from Mixin Method

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have following piece of code and cannot seem to access the mixin data/variable `loading` from mixin method. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Vue.mixin({
    data: function () {
        return {
            loading: false,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        getEntityList: async (entityName) => {
            loading = true 
            return await axios
                .get("/api/" + entityName)
                .then((response) => {
                    loading = false;
                    return response.data;
                });
        },
    },
});
```

In Vue component, I am calling this function like:

```
export default {
  name: "somename",
  data() {
    return {
      accounts: [],
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getEntityList('account').then(e => this.accounts = e);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in condition you are using the options API, you need to reference your `loading` oh yes, vue has a behavior where you need to use "this.function" to declare your functions etc..
with a `this`.

`this.loading = true`
and
`this.loading = false`

Comment: I already tried this, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

A tip, to help! In the browser console, you can put the name of the Vue instance, in your case it is > `Vue.mixin`. One more thing you didn't instantiate anything like below.
For example:

```
var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
```

ok or try something like this.

```
data: {
  loading: false,
  methods:{
  loadingFunction: function () {
    this.loading = false;
    // or return this.loading
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Its instantiated, everything works, I can access this loading variable inside a vue component, but not inside the mixin.

Comment: @HarisurRehman I put a code above editing my comment, try to do something like I put.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`loading` should be `this.loading`, as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669167/3731501) shows. Otherwise it accesses global variable that doesn't exist and isn't specific to a component, also not reactive.

`getEntityList` is arrow function. The choice between regular and arrow function should always be justified. Here an arrow will prevent from using correct `this` context.

`then` doesn't need to be used together with `async..await`, the latter is supposed to replace it.

It should be:

```
    async getEntityList(entityName) {
        this.loading = true 
        let response = await axios
            .get("/api/" + entityName);
        this.loading = false;
        return response.data;
    },
```